# Can you Parameterize an intent creation function?

Tags: android, function, android-activity, android-intent

In order to simplify some code, I'm wondering if it is possible to parameterize code that launches activities in an android application, so that instead of having 5

```
    public void showSettings(View view) {
    Intent SettingsActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class);
    startActivity(SettingsActivity);
```

I can do something like the following

```
 public void showActivity(View view, String ActivityName) {
        Intent ActivityName = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityName.class);
        startActivity(ActivityName);
```

Then, for each button in the UI, I simply apply the following to the "onclick" event

> showActivity(Settings);

or

> showActivity(domains);

This would save about 40-50 lines of code in my app.  Obviously I know the above code is incorrect, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: can't you just pass the class (e.g. ActivityName.class) as parameter to create your intent?

Comment: **Don't** try to simplify your code by passing around strings when you want to refer to other types or objects. The compiler is there to help you put the right objects in the right place - any string matching you do on your own is prone to errors that the compiler could have prevented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
public <T> void showActivity(View view, Class<T> activity) {
    Intent activityName = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity);
    startActivity(activityName);
}
```

You can invoke it with

```
showActivity(Settings.class);
```

Comment: awesome.  I knew string wasn't what I was looking for, but I didn't know how to use just the string portion to label the class.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend use ACTIONs (String) instead of specifying exactly context and class. This way you even can share activities among applications, and if you decide to switch to different activity class, you can edit only android manifest, instead of editing all java source code calls this activity.